# Can't see localStorage keys with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to do a simple JS exercise using localStorage to store some values; when I try to inspect these values using Chrome devtools I can't see the keys

[image]

Is there any setting so that I can see it with every key?

---

Edit:

I am trying to set this value using

```
localStorage.setItem('Try', 'This is a try');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('Try'));
```

and the "This is a try" is correctly logged in the console.

Comment: How are you trying to set those values? Show the code. Or are you trying to set it manually by writing directly in the storage without the use of JS?

Comment: believe me or not, `This is a try` is your key, not the value. There should be another colum on the right labelled "Value" where the value is shown (you'll notice `This is a try` in the image is in the column labelled "Key")

Comment: Actually @Kaddath you are wrong, as irvins said it was only the window moved all the way up; "Try" is the key and "This is a try" is the value.

Comment: Solved my problem, but you are right that it is NOT obvious. The top window completely covers the window with the key/value table below it. +1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your window showing the value seems to be moved all the way up

hover the mouse on the line between the "This is a try" and "Key", click and drag down.

you should see the covered screen then

Comment: so weird, this happens all the time and it's not clear at all, thanks

Comment: @irvins thanks!  I was banging my head against the keyboard trying to figure this out.

Comment: Or follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/customize/localization#reverting-all-devtools-settings-to-the-defaults , If link not working (open dev tool > click setting icon > click reset setting [last option in preference page ] )

Comment: @Ankit This is bananas - I have to do this on every single use of the dev tools. Every time I view Application! I'm on latest Chrome. Is there a permanent fix/workaround?

Comment: @TsarBomba I had faced this issue only once, so not sure what has caused it. If you find anything please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by clicking the button `Chrome Developer Tools > Settings > Preferences > Restore defaults and reload`