# Can't see localStorage key val pairs in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools

I have a json file that stores data which is displayed on my page using javascript. This json file and its key val pairs are not visible or accessible in Chrome's Dev Tools. This component manages json files:

```
/**
 * Takes a filename and a JS object and initiates a download through the browser
 * @param {String} filename
 * @param {any} object JSON serializable object
 * @return {undefined}
 */
export const downloadJson = (filename, object) => {
  const content = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  const el = document.createElement('a');
  el.setAttribute('href', `data:application/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(content)}`);
  el.setAttribute('download', filename);
  el.hidden = true;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.click();
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};

/**
 * Gets the `target.result` property from an event, or returns null
 * if it fails at any point
 * @type {Function}
 * @param {Event} event load Event
 * @return {File}
 */
const getFileResult = propPathOr(null, ['target', 'result']);

/**
 * Takes a file and reads it as JSON, resolving the JSON-parsed
 * file contents
 * @param {File} file
 * @return {Promise<[Object]>} Returns Promise of Array of Archive Entries
 */
export const readFileAsJson = file => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = compose(resolve, JSON.parse, getFileResult);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
  reader.readAsText(file);
  return promise;
};

export const readFileListAsJson = files =>
  Promise.all(
    Array.from(files)
      .map(readFileAsJson)
  )
    .catch(console.error);
```

This is the database component:

```
// DATABASE functions
import { get, set, keys } from 'idb-keyval';
import { sha1 } from './hash.js';

const getKey = key => get(key);

export const getAllEntries = async () =>
  await Promise.all((await keys()).map(getKey));

export const writeMultipleEntries = entries =>
  entries.forEach(writeSingleEntry);

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ArchiveEntry
 * @property {String} date
 * @property {String} passage
 * @property {String} question
 * @property {String} answer
 */

/**
 * Writes a single archive entry to idb
 * @param {ArchiveEntry} entry
 * @return {ArchiveEntry}
 */
export const writeSingleEntry = async ({ date, passage, question, answer }) => {
  const hash = await hashEntry({ date, passage, question });
  await set(hash, { date, passage, question, answer });
  return { date, passage, question, answer };
};

/**
 * Generates a hash of an entry to use as it's idb key
 * @param {ArchiveEntry} entry
 * @return {string}
 */
const hashEntry = ({ date, passage, question }) =>
  sha1(`${date}-${passage}-${question}`);
```

Values are stored using this function:

```
const updateDb =
  ({ passage, question }) =>
  (answer) =>
    writeSingleEntry({ date: new Date(), answer, passage, question });
```

Storage is handled by its own script:

```
export const storeOnInput = key => ({ target: { value } }) => writeValue(key, value);
export const readValue = key => localStorage.getItem(key);
export const writeValue = (key, val) => localStorage.setItem(key, val);
```

It is called in several components. Here to write and read the value of a text passage:

```
onActiveChanged(active) {
  this.passage = readValue('passage-input');
}   

onKeyup(event) {
    writeValue('passage-input', event.target.value);
}
```

Here to write and record a question:

```
onActiveChanged(active) {
  this.question = readValue("question-input");
  this.passage = readValue("passage-input");
}

onKeyup(event) {
   writeValue("question-input", event.target.value);
}
```

Here to provide an answer and reset the form:

```
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
const write = document.getElementById('write');
const question = document.getElementById('question');

const onAnswerSubmitted = ({ detail: answer }) => {
  writeValue('answer', answer);
};

onActiveChanged(active) {
  if (!active) return;
  this.answer = readValue('answer');
}

resetQuestion() {
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('reset-question'));
  writeValue('question-input', '');
  writeValue('answer', '');
}

resetWrite() {
  this.resetQuestion();
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('reset-passage'));
  writeValue('passage-input', '');
}
```

Here to get entries:

```
  onActiveChanged(active) {
    if (active) this.getEntries();
  }

 async getEntries() {
    this.entries = await getAllEntries();
    this.entry = new URLSearchParams(location.search.substring(1)).get("date");
    console.log("here are the dates: \n", prettyDate(this.entries[0].date));
    console.log("here is an answer: \n", this.entries[0].answer);
  }
```

Here to download and upload the JSON file:

```
  async exportBackup() {
    downloadJson(`backup ${new Date()}.json`, await getAllEntries());
  }

  async importBackup({ target: { files } }) {
    return readFileListAsJson(files)
      .then(map(writeMultipleEntries));
  }
```

[Unlike this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371406/cant-see-localstorage-keys-with-chrome-developer-tools), nothing is showing in Storage > Local Storage, and it is not
a Chrome UI design flaw issue.
[image: Image of Dev Tools Local Storage panel]

It is possible to confirm the values have been written and are are accessible from the json file using functions like:

```
console.log(this.entries[0].date)
console.log(this.entries[0].answer)
```

but I would like to be able to debug by viewing the entire json file.

Comment: Please share how you are using the local storage utility functions?

Comment: It is important for us to see the code that calls the `writevalue()` function so we can help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: Maybe because you are searching "date" text?!

Comment: @RandyCasburn and MahdiJoon, thanks. I've added in the read/write code. Date is specifically recorded as 'date' for each entry, and as mentioned is viewable using console.log()

Comment: great - but there still is no code that does anything with your JSON that your question addresses! There is not code that does anything with the `this.entries` that  you console log. Please provide _that_ code - it is impossible for us to determine what is happening if you don't show us the code _that your question is all about_. Thanks.

Comment: You never write any `entity` to `localStorage`. No code provided that deals with multiple entries or single entry ever calls `writeValue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem today while working on my webapp :

- I could access some data i registered on the localstorage via the console (`JSON.parse(localStorage["my-storage-key"]`)
- But in the Chrome dev tools, in the Application tab, the `https://localhost:4200` entry was totaly empty, just like in the screen capture you provided.

What fixed the problem for me was to click "Restore defaults and reload" in the preferences of the chrome DevTools, and i could see the entries in the table again.

[image: Restore defaults and reload button in the chrome devtools preferences panel]

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't appear as though you have loaded the JSON file into local storage at any point. Perhaps there is driver code which you can share so that your issue can be more easily debugged.

In the meantime, checkout the documentation for [localstorage on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I think you may find the answer by reading up on how to set local storage.

Comment: Makes for a great comment, but not _really_ an actionable answer since we don't have enough information to leap all that way to your conclusion.

Comment: If the JSON file isn't loaded, how is it being read in console?

Comment: Please see my comment about not writing to `localStorage`. If you include that comment or anything related to the additional details provided in the question, I'll remove my downvote.